# Error while starting ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby. I am trying to start the ruby server using the command `bundle exec rails server -p 3018`. But I am getting the below error. I checked in the code, there is no `newrelic.yml` file.

```
Cannot find or read /Users/hjodiawalla/Downloads/TheGiftsProject-Plugin/config/newrelic.yml
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928:in 'initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::Error)
Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928:in 'connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928:in 'connect'
```

How do I resolve the issue. The server was working before with the same configuration. So have I missed something here.

Comment: I would check if your database is set up and configured correctly

Comment: Try using a SQLite for now instead of Postgres. Might be easier to work with when you're first starting out.

Comment: @claasz Thanks. Checking the database did solve the issue

Comment: @claptimes I will look into using SQLite. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install a `config/newrelic.yml` file. ([docs](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-installation))